Export custom list as .xlsx ( excel file ) instead of Microsoft Excel Web Query File (.iqy) in Team Site SharePoint 2019 On Premise
I created a custom list in Team Site in SharePoint 2019 and created list items with custom columns,
here i when i tried to export to excel it saves as Microsoft Excel Web Query File (.iqy) but
here i required to export as complete .xlsx ( excel file )

Dealing with those .iqy files can be a bit of a hassle. Unfortunately, SharePoint 2019 doesn't directly support exporting lists to .xlsx format.
There are several custom codes approaches you can implement to achieve this:

PowerShell scripts/console applications
Custom web parts
Command bar extensions on list views

